# RichTextFX comment and property regex

Tags: java, regex, javafx, richtextfx

I am trying to use the RichTextFX library to show a properties file in the `CodeArea`. I have created some Regex for comments as well as properties to try to style to `CodeArea`. 
EDIT: I am able to get them working properly. Except for when I add a comment to a line that has a property. My regex for determining a Property is not able to tell when there's a `#` at the beginning of the line. I have tried but am unable to get it to negate the rest of it if it sees there is a `#` at the beginning.

Here's the two patterns that I am using:

`Pattern COMMENT = Pattern.compile("(?<SingleLineComment>#+)(?<Comment>.*\n)");`

`Pattern PROPERTY = Pattern.compile("(\n?(?<PropertyName>.+)(\\h*=\\h*)(?<PropertyValue>\\S+))");`

Here's how they are being used in code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.model.StyleSpans;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.model.StyleSpansBuilder;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest extends Application
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        _area = new CodeArea();
        _area.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/settings-design.css").toExternalForm());
        _area.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(_area));

        _area.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            computeHighlighting(newValue);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(_area, 400, 600));

        primaryStage.show();

        _area.appendText(PROPERTIES);
    }

    private void computeHighlighting(String text) {
        Matcher equalsTest = COMMENT.matcher(text);
        while (equalsTest.find()){
            _area.setStyle( equalsTest.start(), equalsTest.end(), Collections.singleton("comment"));
        }

        Matcher propertyMatcher = PROPERTY.matcher(text);
        while (propertyMatcher.find()){
            _area.setStyle(propertyMatcher.start(1), propertyMatcher.end(3), Collections.singleton("property-name"));
            _area.setStyle(propertyMatcher.start(4), propertyMatcher.end(4), Collections.singleton("property-value"));
        }
    }

    private CodeArea _area;

    private static final Pattern COMMENT = Pattern.compile("(?<SingleLineComment>#+\\h*)(?<Comment>.*)\n?");
    private static final Pattern PROPERTY = Pattern.compile("(?:[#].+|(\n?(?<PropertyName>.+)(\\h*=\\h*)(?<PropertyValue>\\S+)))");

    private static final Pattern EQUALSTEST = Pattern.compile("=");

    public static final String PROPERTIES = "#Tue Nov 06 12:42:33 CST 2018\n" +
            "#prop0=true";
```

And `code-area.css`:

```
.comment {
    -fx-fill: #008e00;
}

.property-name {
    -fx-fill: #ff8e31;
}

.property-value {
    -fx-fill: #58a3ff;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you please include the error you're seeing?

Comment: The error isn't the problem. I know that the error that's being thrown is because the Regex is not matching properly

Comment: OK, well we know that now, which is a step forwards. If that's not the problem, could you describe what you expect to see happen, and what does happen instead.

Comment: Tim, I updated my post since I figured out most of the problem. The new problem now is in the edit part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for parsing a property file line into it's key-divider-value-comment parts that is Java complaint.

```
^\s*(?:|(?<PropertyName>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)(?<Divider>\s*[=: ]\s*)(?<PropertyValue>\w(?:.|\\,|\\[\n\r\f\v]+)*))(?<Comment>[#!].*)?$
```

Note that this regex is still not exhaustive, and the built in [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class is much more suited to this task than regex. (Use the load function to parse the source, and than it basically works like a Map)